# displaying custom tooltip on chart points

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, events, charts

I am looking for a chat library where i can show custom tool tips on chart points. and can give click events on axis and points.

I have wasted lot of my time for Google all these but can't find all these feature in chart library.

Please suggest me chart api which have all such features.

Comment: http://www.jqplot.com/ - Found by googling "jquery chart plugin" and opening the second link that showed up.

Comment: I tried with it but not full filling all requirements . I can't see click events

Comment: It has hover events on everything, can't you bind a click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Open Flash Chart 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/)

**It's Basic features are :**

It provides functions for custom Tool-tips, user interactivity and data exploration

you can re-size the charts

Can save the chart as an image

You can highlight or emphasize one (or many) points

You can Perform click events on it's elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tooltips with Google's Visualization Chart. As an example, the following adds a tooltip to a bar chart:

```
function drawVisualization() {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number');
    data.addColumn({type:'string',role:'tooltip'});
    data.addRow();
    base = 10;
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Datapoint1');
    data.setValue(0, 1, base++);
    data.setValue(0, 2, " This is my tooltip1 ");

    data.addRow();
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Datapoint2');
    data.setValue(1, 1, base++);
    data.setValue(1, 2, "This is my second tooltip2");

    // Draw the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {legend:'none', width:600, height:400});
}
```